Limit of proportionality for compression of materials
Similar to how there is a limit of proportionality for the extension of materials, is there a limit of proportionality for the compression of materials. If there is, then what sort of structural changes would typically occur in the material and would these changes be similar to those experienced by materials which are stretched under tensile deformation beyond the limit of proportionality.

Are you referring to hydrostatic compression, or uniaxial compression? Also what type of material, metal, polymer, ceramic ...?

I am referring to uniaxial compression. I am not trying to refer to any material or object in particular since I just wanted to know if there is any possibility of a limit of proportionality existing for the compression of any material or object

The answer to you question is very material dependent. Metals yield in uniaxial compression at very  nearly the same stress level as they do in tension, i.e. the limit of proportionality is the same in tension and compression. Other materials can have different proportional limits in tension and compression due to different mechanisms being active.
